# Vertical endless scrolling background in sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scroll, sprite-kit

I'm making a game and I'd like to have my background *scroll vertically endlessly* but I have no clue how to start. I'm pretty new to coding and sprite kit especially so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Anyone know how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you an answer conceptually to give you a place to start since you have not provided any code.

You will need multiple images that are the size of the screen and stack them on top of each other vertically.

You then want to move these images down point by point. When the top of one of the images reaches the bottom of the screen, put it back on top of your stack of images. This will cause a never ending scrolling of your background.

Best of luck!

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Thanks! How many copies of the same image would u recommend as a good amount though?

Comment: It really depends on how diverse you want your background to be. For example, if it were a game where you fly an airplane forward and the background scrolls vertically and you only had 2 images one with a ship and one with an island, users may realize it is just a repeating background. But if you just had an ocean, you may be able to get away with just 2 as water is water everywhere. Depending on your art and what you want to achieve it varies so test some out to see what fits for you.

Answer (score 2):

You want to have two nodes, one to start with and one that follows it.  Lastly, loop forever.

```
 func createGroundForward() {
        let groundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Track")

        for i in 0 ... 1 {
            let ground = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
            ground.zPosition = -4
            ground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -groundTexture.size().height + (groundTexture.size().height   + (groundTexture.size().height * CGFloat(i))))

            addChild(ground)

            let moveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x:0 , y: -groundTexture.size().height, duration: 5)
            let moveReset = SKAction.moveBy(x:0 , y: groundTexture.size().height, duration: 0)
            let moveLoop = SKAction.sequence([moveLeft, moveReset])
            let moveForever = SKAction.repeatForever(moveLoop)

            ground.run(moveForever)
        }
    }
```

Then add the function to your didMove function (which is like viewDidLoad for Sprite).

```
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        createGroundForward()
    }
```